# How to create an image on the fly with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, image, express, html5-canvas

I'm using Node.js and Express web framework, I need to create an on-the-fly image **.png** or **.jpg** (like captcha), then I have to send that image to the browser.

What is the simplest way to do that?
In the image I should write letters/numbers (max 5).

P.S. I don't know what library to use that connects to an online service as the recaptcha module does.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you could use [canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element)? There is also an [implementation in node.js by Learnboost(TJ)](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas). I think [this screencast](https://web.archive.org/web/20180311114716/http://www.screenr.com:80/CTk) is interesting to look at. As you see from presentation it even renders text in some examples. Also in the [npm registry](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/modules) / [node modules section](https://web.archive.org/web/20120730011028/http://search.npmjs.org:80/) I found a lot more interesting links

Answer (score 8):

Here's some simple code using the [canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) library:

```js
const
    fs = require("fs"),
    { createCanvas } = require("canvas");

const WIDTH = 100;
const HEIGHT = 50;

const canvas = createCanvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#222222";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
ctx.fillStyle = "#f2f2f2";
ctx.font = "32px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello", 13, 35);

const buffer = canvas.toBuffer("image/png");
fs.writeFileSync("test.png", buffer);
```

This is the resulting `test.png` file:

[image: Sample output image]

To run it, you must first install the library:

```sh
npm i canvas
```

Instead of saving it to a file, you could, of course, send it as the response of an API call.

For more details on how to draw text using the canvas, see this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text).

Comment: How would I get the results?

Comment: @Niso if you mean the image, check the line `fs.writeFileSync("test.png", buffer);`, which writes the results to a file named `test.png`.

Comment: Cool, thank you @Lucio. I did not notice that earlier.