# Generate PNG image using node.js

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to create a PNG image from a pixel data array using Node.js? I'd like to create a PNG image from an array of RGBA values, and then save it to a file.

Comment: I'd check Google first: https://github.com/pkrumins/node-png

Comment: I also found this: https://github.com/pkrumins/node-image

Comment: Which libPNG package will I need to install in order to use node-png?

Comment: It's the libpng library. Most Linux distributions ship with it: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

Comment: I've noticed that each of the example png-js scripts contain the line `var Png = require('../png').Png;`. What should I replace `'../png'` with?

Comment: I found an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062812/how-to-create-an-image-on-the-fly-with-node-js

Comment: @Blender Is it possible to install node-png using npm?

Answer (score 27):

You can use [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp).

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');


let imageData = [
  [ 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF ],
  [ 0xFF0000FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0xFF0000FF ],
  [ 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0x0000FFFF ]
];


let image = new Jimp(3, 3, function (err, image) {
  if (err) throw err;

  imageData.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((color, x) => {
      image.setPixelColor(color, x, y);
    });
  });

  image.write('test.png', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

This code creates a png file 3x3 pixels with the colors defined in the array.

Comment: Hi, any idea how can I build that `imageData` array out of an array of pixels like `[ ... [r, g, b], [5, 63, 255] ...]`?

Comment: @Frondor, you just should use `Jimp.rgbaToInt(r, g, b, a);` to build a color in hex format.

Comment: Yeah, figured out after a few google searches. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this is a 5MB dependency for just "writing a file", which is pretty crazy. You're better off with something like [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs)

Comment: While pngjs can decode an indexed PNG, it does not export/encode indexed color palette PNGs.