# How to write a pixel array to file/png with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, pixel

I have an pixel array (RGBA values) like this

```
data = [
          255,    // R
          255,    // G
          255,    // B
          255,    // A
          0,      // R
          0,      // G
          0,      // B
          255,    // A
          ...
        ];
```

It is actually obtained somewhere in the process from a canvas with `getImageData`. Anyway, now in node I would like to write it to file as a png (jpg or gif is fine too) What would be the best tool to do this, given the array I've described above ?

Comment: Look at comments for [Generate PNG image using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380841/generate-png-image-using-node-js)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/save-pixels this may help you as well

Comment: Thnx, I managed to use save-pixels to write it too file!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Can you show us how exactly did you do it with save-pixels? I cannot find an example where one can paste rgba values into the image. :/