# With NPM glob, how can I change directories from where the script is actually located?

Tags: javascript, glob

I want to use the [NPM glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) package to traverse a directory that, from the calling file, is `../../aFolder/targetFolder`.  This is the way I've tried to do it:

```
try{
    options = {
        cwd: '../../aFolder/targetFolder' 
    }
    glob('*.jpg', (err,files)=>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(files);
        }
    })
}
catch(e){
    console.log("I am error: ", e);
}
```

I get an empty array. I know for the fact that the folder I want to look into has .jpg files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass your `options` object into the `glob()` function call.

```
try {
  options = {
    cwd: '../../aFolder/targetFolder' 
  }
  glob('*.jpg', options, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(files);
    }
  })
}
catch(e) {
  console.log("I am error: ", e);
}
```

Comment: ok in that case,  how can I overwrite files found in that folder with the contents (or copy of the file itself) of another file? They're all picture files I'm dealing with. Thanks @daniel-bank

Comment: actually, I wanna replace the contents (tho not the file name) with a 1x1 jpg pixel, bc they're all image files. How can I do that?

Comment: You can do something as described in this StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380841/generate-png-image-using-node-js