# Android: downloading image generated on the fly from the server

Tags: android, node.js, image, download

I'm developing an app that lets the user combine up to ten images from 100,000 pre-made images into one.  I of course don't want to pre-generate every possible combination, and would rather the server combine the combinations on the fly to send to the user. Is there a way to:

- Generate the image combination that was requested by the user on the server and then send it to the Android user without having to first download the combination onto the server.  That way I won't have to turnaround and delete immediately after.

if not, does that mean I have to:

- generate the image
- store that image on the server
- get the url of where it is stored
- send that image to the user's phone
- notify the server that it has been downloaded so it can then
- delete the generated image

If it helps I'm using node.js and https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas to combine the images.

Comment: 'without having to first download the combination onto the server' ????? Where would that come from? Of course the generation on the fly is a nice task for the server.

Comment: 'generate the image'. Ok 'store that image on the server'. Not needed. 'get the url of where it is stored'. As a consequence there is no extra url. 'send that image to the user's phone'. When the client requests the server to generate a specific image the server will send it immediately as answer to that request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand Node.js, but yes it is possible. Just to be a long query.

1) Request for Picture

2) Server generate a Picture(long query)

3) Server are giving the image to client (load data)

The main thing is to generate the correct page. (image data) Look at [it](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062812/how-to-create-an-image-on-the-fly-with-node-js).