# Is it possible to add text over an image by passing the text as a query parameter to the image URL?

Tags: javascript, image

I was able to add Text over an Image from HTML or by using a library in Backend to append text over an image before the page is rendered.

I was wondering if it's possible to add text over an Image and create a new Image from the Query Parameter passed to the Image URL while the page is rendered in frontend?

Also, I would need to send the same Image via email as well, I guess the frontend solution might get complicated when I'm sending an email.

Update:
I found a tool online which is doing exactly what I need - https://imagekit.io/

Any idea on how they are able to draw the text so fast?

Answer (score 0):

You could use both:

1. The backend option is more straightforward. In your programming language (php, node.js etc) you initialize an empty image, then copy the needed image from the get parameter, then add the text from the get parameter and then output the image contents. This should be a controller destination and link to it directly
2. For the client side option you can use JS to add the `data-test` property over the image, or if it's not possible and then use regex to extract it from the url.

```js
const image = document.getElementById('img')
img.textContent = img.dataset.text
```

```css
#img {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="img" style="background-image: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/photos/1960131820/display_1500/stock-photo-sunset-at-coast-of-the-lake-nature-landscape-nature-in-northern-europe-reflection-blue-sky-and-1960131820.jpg)" data-text="Nice Sunset"></div>
```

Comment: I need to send the same Image via email as well. Guess I forgot to mention that in the question. Will update it.

Comment: In that case the back end solution is the only viable one, since html in emails is poorly supported. Check this answer for a node.js solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59365344/13817884